# Name of This Black and White Dove

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I spotted this dove in a park. It was foraging among Rock Doves, Seagulls, Ibises and a few others.

It appears similar to Pied Rock Doves, but I am not certain if this is correct.

[image]

Any idea what the name of this dove is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a pied version of the Rock Pigeon (*Columbia livia*), aka Rock Dove. According to the [Cornell Lab of Ornithology](http://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/rock_pigeon/lifehistory), the pied variety of Rock Pigeon is one of any color that has splotches of white on the body. I think that fits your bird very well. It's not a different species, but just one of several color varieties of Rock Pigeon.

If you are not familiar with Cornell's site and enjoy birds, their All About Birds site is very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Also called Piebald (Pied for short as mentioned above.) It's a pretty common mutation among different animals. Dogs, deer, and snakes such as the ball python exhibit this trait. So yeah, your bird is still a rock dove.

Answer (score -3):

[image] the bird above is a pigeon, local breed of pigeon in African, just like any other pigeon, it has all features a pigeon has! It was got as a result of mating a brown male pigeon with a black white colored female pigeon, All local breeds from Africa!?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and thus is inappropriate for this site. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then delete or edit your answer accordingly.